# Difficulties Returning a Dynamic Pivoted Table From a SQL Function - "Must Declare the table variable xxx"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot-table, stored-functions

**Summary**:

My stored procedure is returning "Must declare the table variable "@InitialData" when run.

**Detail**:

The data in my table looks like this:

| Code | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1-1-2020 | $1,500 |
| 001 | 2-1-2020 | $3,500 |
| 002 | 1-1-2020 | $500 |
| 002 | 2-1-2020 | $7000 |

My goal is to pivot the data like this, and return it to the application.

| Code | 1-1-2020 | 2-1-2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | $1,500 | $3,500 |
| 002 | $500 | $7000 |

To further filter the data returned, I am using a function to return some queried data called **ReturnEVMTotals**, which takes three parameters:

- **Project ID**: Retrieve only data for the desired project.
- **Status Date**: Retrieve only data up to the given date.
- **Scale**: Return the data grouped by year, month, or week. Work in progress.

None of this information is directly related to task at hand, but I figure it should help make some sense of this stored procedure:

```
sp_ReturnPivotTotals 
    @intUProj int, 
    @dateStatus date,
    @strScale varchar(10)

DECLARE @InitialData TABLE 
        (
        intProjectID int, 
        strCC varchar(50), 
        decAmount decimal(18,2), 
        DateType varchar(50)
        )

    INSERT INTO @InitialData 
        SELECT intProjectID, strCC, decAmount, DateType FROM [dbo].[ReturnEVMTotals] (@intUProj,@dateStatus,@strScale)
    
    DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @Columns =
        COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(DateType)
        FROM
           (SELECT DISTINCT DateType
            FROM   @InitialData
           ) AS B
        ORDER BY DateType

DECLARE @ReturnTable VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ReturnTable = 'SELECT * FROM @InitialData  AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(decAmount)
        FOR DateType IN ('+@Columns+')
    ) AS PivotTable'

EXEC(@ReturnTable)

END
```

When I try to run the procedure, I receive the following error:

**Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the table variable "@InitialData".**

- I suspect that the issue is that the **EXEC(@ReturnTable)** command is executing against the **database**, not the table variable in the procedure. However:
- I am having major trouble figuring out the best way to retrieve a dynamic pivot table that retrieves it's initial data from a function with parameters (**ReturnEVMTotals**).

I have managed to do my work for a pretty long time without asking questions, and just Googling the information I don't know. This has me completely stumped.

Please help, and thank you.

Comment: `@InitialData` doesn't exist in the context of your dynamic SQL. You'll need to create a table `TYPE` and then pass it as a parameter to your dynamic SQL. You can't do that with `EXEC ({Variable});` though, you'll need to execute the dynamic SQL properly with `sys.sp_executesql`. Alternatively you could use a temporary table instead (though I still recommend using `sys.sp_executesql`).

Comment: Also, don't prefix your procedure names with `sp_`. The prefix is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures. Using the prefix comes with a performance cost and could mean your procedure will simply stop working update an update/upgrade.

Comment: I absolutely understand my prefix mistake. I feel like I knew that once, but I forgot. Fixed that.

Table TYPES seem to assume that I know the columns that will be returned. I have no idea the number of columns that could be returned. It could range from between '1/1/2020' to '1/1/2022' and every month in between, or it could range from back in the 90's. Am I misunderstanding the use of table types?

Comment: *"Table TYPES seem to assume that I know the columns that will be returned"* You `INSERT` the data into `@InitialData` outside of the dynamic statement not inside it, in the above. So you do know the definition.

Comment: Your table variable is out of scope in the dynamic query. Use a `#` temp table instead. Note by the way, that `SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','')...` is undefined syntax, and may return incorrect results, especially with an `ORDER BY` clause. Use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead. Also you should always declare dynamic SQL variables as `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let's clarify the reason for your error. This is because inside the dynamic statement you haven't declared or defined the variable `@InitialData`. It is only defined *outside* of the dynamic statement, but variables are only available in the scope you defined them in so you can't use it.

If you *had* to use a table variable, you'd need to define a table type first, and then use that parametrise that.

Firstly, create the type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.InitialData AS table (ProjectID int,        --Don't prefix your column names with the data type,
                                      CC varchar(50),       --it isn't needed. It also doesn't make a lot of sense
                                      Amount decimal(18,2), --when you name the last column in this table as DateType
                                      DateType varchar(50));--but it's not a date, it's a varchar. That's confusing.
```

And then your proc would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.ReturnPivotTotals  --Removed sp_ prefix
    @intUProj int, 
    @dateStatus date,
    @strScale varchar(10)
AS --This was missing
BEGIN --This was also missing as you had a END
    DECLARE @InitialData dbo.InitialData

    INSERT INTO @InitialData 
    SELECT intProjectID, strCC, decAmount, DateType FROM [dbo].[ReturnEVMTotals] (@intUProj,@dateStatus,@strScale);
    
    DECLARE @Columns as NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @Columns =
        COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(DateType)
        FROM
           (SELECT DISTINCT DateType
            FROM   @InitialData
           ) AS B
        ORDER BY DateType

DECLARE @ReturnTable NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ReturnTable = 'SELECT * FROM @InitialData  AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(decAmount)
        FOR DateType IN ('+@Columns+')
    ) AS PivotTable'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @ReturnTable, N'@InitialData dbo.InitialData READONLY', @InitialData;

END
GO
```

Alternatively you could use a temporary table, which will be exposed in the inner scope:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.ReturnPivotTotals  --Removed sp_ prefix
    @intUProj int, 
    @dateStatus date,
    @strScale varchar(10)
AS --This was missing
BEGIN --This was also missing as you had a END
    CREATE TABLE #InitialData (ProjectID int,        --Again, don't prefix your column names with the data type.
                               CC varchar(50),       
                               Amount decimal(18,2), 
                               DateType varchar(50));
    INSERT INTO @InitialData 
    SELECT intProjectID, strCC, decAmount, DateType FROM [dbo].[ReturnEVMTotals] (@intUProj,@dateStatus,@strScale);
    
    DECLARE @Columns as NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @Columns =
        COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(DateType)
        FROM
           (SELECT DISTINCT DateType
            FROM  #InitialData
           ) AS B
        ORDER BY DateType

DECLARE @ReturnTable NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ReturnTable = 'SELECT * FROM #InitialData  AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(decAmount)
        FOR DateType IN ('+@Columns+')
    ) AS PivotTable'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @ReturnTable;

END
GO
```

Truthfully though, do you need the table variable/temporary table? Assuming your function is a well written inline table value function, I *assume* it's quite performant and returns the data quickly. Also, as [Charlieface mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68445145/difficulties-returning-a-dynamic-pivoted-table-from-a-sql-function-must-decla#comment120964203_68445145) don't use undocumented behaviour; there's no guarantee the syntax will work. Instead use `FOR XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG`. I'll use `FOR XML PATH` here, as we don't know your SQL Server version:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.ReturnPivotTotals  --Removed sp_ prefix
    @UProj int, --Don't prefix your variable names with the data type either
    @Status date,
    @Scale varchar(10)
AS --This was missing
BEGIN --This was also missing as you had a END
    
    DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Columns = STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(DateType)
                          FROM [dbo].[ReturnEVMTotals] (@UProj,@Status,@Scale)
                          GROUP BY DateType
                          ORDER BY DateType
                          FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'');

    DECLARE @ReturnTable NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ReturnTable = 'SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[ReturnEVMTotals] (@UProj,@Status,@Scale) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(decAmount)
        FOR DateType IN ('+@Columns+')
    ) AS PivotTable'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @ReturnTable, N'@UProj int, @Status date, @Scale varchar(10)', @UProj, @Status, @Scale;

END
GO
```

Comment: That looks perfect, and makes a lot of sense.

This part is complaining:     SET @Columns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT N',' + QUOTENAME(DateType)
                          FROM [dbo].[ReturnEVMTotals] (@UProj,@Status,@Scale)
                          ORDER BY DateType
                          FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'');

It says "**ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.**", which seems odd as I can see DateType listed right there.

Comment: Remove the `DISTINCT` and add `GROUP BY DateType`.

Comment: Also, I swapped out the buggy piece with my old, undocumented behavior, and it works perfect! So thank you so much for your help. I'll keep working to figure out what's wrong with the code above, and everything should be smooth. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've fixed the about now too. If this solves the problem, please do mark it as the solution as well @DustinVentin . This lets future readers know that the answer was helpful.

Comment: @Larnu Looks like you fell in the classic trap: `DISTINCT` means that only columns in the select list can be used in `ORDER BY`, not any other columns, for obvious reasons (`DISTINCT` is a `GROUP BY` all columns)

Comment: It's more that I couldn't test the code, due to a lack of sample data, and I copied the OP's syntax @Charlieface .

Comment: I'm probably going to use the temp table solution, as I actually need to massage the data a bit more (bring in some detail from the master table) before it's ready to ship. I'll keep you up to date, if you like.

Comment: This is such a pain. If you were to try and take the result set from the code above, and have to combine it with a table of master data, how would you do it? I can't call the stored procedure from another function or stored procedure, because (again), I have no idea how many columns are coming out the other end. And I can't change this to a function, because a table function also has to have a predefined table output. I think you can see the source of my confusion?

Comment: Then don't pivot your data, @DustinVentin . You are creating the issue by denormalising it. Ideally pivoting should be done in the presentation layer. This is why you are having problems, because you're making denormalised data and then wondering why it's hard to use; it's hard to use *because* it's denormalised.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. I already have the pivot coded on the front end, but I was trying to move the pivot to the SQL Server because I assumed it would be faster. I suppose it's good to know I had things done right the first time.